# Convert array to new field, using keys as the values of this array and values as frequency of these items (aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this problem, but I can't solve it.
I have to transform the array `s` to a new field called `shares`.
This new field have inside new keys and new values.
Suppose I have these documents:

```
{
  'name': 'igor',
  's': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
},
{
  'name': 'jones',
  's': ['c', 'b']
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  'name': 'igor',
  'shares': {
     'a': 3
     'b': 2
  }
},
{
  'name': 'jones',
  'shares': {
     'c': 1
     'b': 1
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: I tried to use $sum inside group stage, with $switch stage. This works, but I have to create the fields manually.

Comment: It's recommended to post what have you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** unwind `s` array */
    {
      $unwind: "$s"
    },
    /** group on unique pairs of `_id + s` & retain name field, count sum of matching docs */
    {
      $group: { _id: { k: "$s", _id: "$_id" }, name: { $first: "$name" }, v: { $sum: 1 } }
    },
    /** group on unique pairs of just `_id` & retain name field, push docs into shares array `[{k :..., v:...}]` */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$_id._id", name: { $first: "$name" }, shares: { $push: { k: "$_id.k", v: "$v" } } }
    },
    /** Re-create shares field from array to object */
    {
      $addFields: { shares: { $arrayToObject: "$shares" } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a4JWpIuPkkZ)

Comment: Why do you get $first name?

Comment: @igorkf : There are only few operators that `$group` can accept like `$push`,`$sum`,`$avg`, `$last`, `$addToSet`, `$first`,... So out of which when you group on `_id` you'll have same `name` for all docs for a unique `_id`. If we use `$push`/`$addToSet` will result in `['igor','igor'...]`, So instead we can use `$first` or `$last` to get it as a string `igor`(`$first` will get value from first document in iteration on group stage for particular `_id`).

Comment: That was nice. I spent too much time trying and now you nailed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to add heterogeneous elements (in your case: `'a': 3, 'b': 2`) to an array, I converted `shares`'s type to something like:

```
{
    key: "$_id.shares",
    count: "$count"
}
```

You need to do the following in order:

1. Unwind the array `s`.
2. Group by composite _ids `name` and `s`.
3. Again group by _id `_id.name` and push objects of type `key` and `count` to the `shares` array.

You can try the below query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$s"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        shares: "$s"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.name",
      shares: {
        $push: {
          key: "$_id.shares",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "jones",
    "shares": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "c"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "key": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "igor",
    "shares": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "key": "a"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "key": "b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC1T60Z-8hU)

Comment: This don't solve the problem because I don't want fields called `keys`.

Comment: Okay, then in that case @whoami 's answer is best. But, I was just suggesting to keep the arrays as homogeneous, as the retrieving part will be easy.